# Replace dataframe with its alias in select in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, alias

I am trying to learn about the dataframe alias command in pyspark. Here is what I observe.

Suppose I have a sample dataframe

```py
t1_df = spark.createDataFrame([['a'], ['b']], 'c1: string')

print(t1_df.show())
+---+
| c1|
+---+
|  a|
|  b|
+---+
```

Now I have created its alias

```py
t2_df = t1_df.alias('df1')
```

If I select the second dataframe's column from the first dataframe, it will work fine as follows

```py
t1_df.select(t2_df.c1)

+---+
| c1|
+---+
|  a|
|  b|
+---+
```

However, if I try the same with alias, it doesn't work

```py
t1_df.select(col('df1.c1'))

AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name `df1`.`c1` cannot be resolved. Did you mean one of the following? [`c1`].;
'Project ['df1.c1]
+- LogicalRDD [c1#3311], false
```

Why is it so? How does an alias work? I don't have any specific purpose for the following, I am just interested and experimenting with things.

I am using Spark version 3.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `df1` keyword is only recognizable when the dataframe `t2_df` is in the query. The `df1` keyword itself doesn't create anything special and is just added as an extra notation in the metadata of the column.

To see that, we need to build the code in scala and run the following query.

```scala
t2_df.select("c1").queryExecution.analyzed.prettyJson
```

```
Output

[ {
  "class" : "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project",
  "num-children" : 1,
  "projectList" : [ [ {
    "class" : "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeReference",
    "num-children" : 0,
    "name" : "c1",
    "dataType" : {
      "type" : "array",
      "elementType" : "string",
      "containsNull" : true
    },
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { },
    "exprId" : {
      "product-class" : "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ExprId",
      "id" : 6,
      "jvmId" : "3271baa8-0b0d-4e6c-bf89-f982cb40a636"
    },
    "qualifier" : "[df1]"         // This is the metadata added
  } ] ],
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception message clearly states that the column `df1.c1` does not exist in the `t1_df` DataFrame:

```
pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] The column or function parameter with the name `df1`.`c1` cannot be resolved. Did you mean one of the following? [`c1`]
```

- Resolving `t2_df.c1` will result in `Column<'c1'>`, and since the `c1` column does exist in the `t1_df` DataFrame, it executes successfully.
- Resolving `col('df1.c1')` will result in `Column<'df1.c1'>`. However, this column does not exist in the `t1_df` DataFrame, leading to the exception `AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION]`.

You can check query plans as both plans are `not` match.

`t1_df.explain(True)`

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
LogicalRDD [c1#8], false

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
c1: string
LogicalRDD [c1#8], false

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
LogicalRDD [c1#8], false

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Scan ExistingRDD[c1#8]
```

`t2_df.explain(True)`

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
SubqueryAlias df1
+- LogicalRDD [c1#8], false

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
c1: string
SubqueryAlias df1
+- LogicalRDD [c1#8], false

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
LogicalRDD [c1#8], false

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Scan ExistingRDD[c1#8]
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, aren't t2_df and df1 the same? Don't they refer to the same column?

Comment: nope, both are not same DataFrame's, alias is available in `t2_df` but not in `t1_df`

Comment: check attached image, alias is available only in`t2_df` but not in `t1_df`

Comment: Please accept answer & upvote if you agree with this.

Comment: I don't understand. If the resolving was just done on the basis of name, then t1_df can select any random column named c1 from any dataframe, but it is not possible. The names are resolved internally using the attributeref you mentioned in other question. So shouldn't that attributeref be used to resolve the column name from the aliased dataframe as well?

Comment: Think logically, Can you access column_1 of table_1 in table_2 where column_1 does not exit in table_2 without any relation ?

Comment: I get that and that is the basis of my question. Alias is just another name for a dataframe, if I can use t2_df, then shouldn't I be able to use df1 as well? Shouldn't these be interchangeable? since they are just names

Comment: I'm thinking like a pointer and object where two pointers point to the same object. Two names (df_t2 and df1) but one object.

Comment: nope, not same object.. both are different objects

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257034/discussion-between-dhruv-and-s-polam).

Comment: Hey, can we discuss more?

Comment: Hey, I was comparing t2_df and its alias df1, not t1_df and t2_df